# Can we define parity operators for spins that are anything like the usual parity operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, parity

In the course of solving a problem I found that it would be useful for me to invent a unitary operator $U$ which satisfies the following requirements for a spin-1/2 system:

$$U^{\dagger}S_{x}U=S_{x}, \hspace{10pt}U^{\dagger}S_{y}U=S_{y}, \hspace{10pt} U^{\dagger}S_{z}U=-S_{z}$$

I've convinced myself this isn't possible, by the following chain of equalities:

$$S_{y}S_{z}=iS_{x} \Rightarrow U^{\dagger}S_{y}S_{z}U=U^{\dagger}S_{y}UU^{\dagger}S_{z}U=-S_{y}S_{z}=iU^{\dagger}S_{x}U=iS_{x}=S_{y}S_{z}$$

which contradicts the unitarity of $U$. But if I try to apply classical reasoning to spins (dangerous, I know, but hear me out), it seems like we should be able to realize the desired transformation by rotating by $\pi$ about the z-axis, which maps $S_{y}\rightarrow -S_{y}$ and $S_{x}\rightarrow -S_{x}$, followed by something resembling the parity operator in spin space, i.e., the operator that sends $S_{x}\rightarrow -S_{x}, S_{y}\rightarrow -S_{y}, S_{z}\rightarrow -S_{z}$. If such an operator existed, it should be unitary and Hermitian, since it squares to the identity. But if such an operator existed, then I can construct the desired $U$, which I just proved can't exist. Can someone point out where my logic is failing me?

Comment: So you demonstrate the U of the first line, or else the "something resembling" operator multiplying all generators with a - sign  is not an isomorphism of the SU(2) algebra--it does not preserve it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to describe is essentially a reflection. The problem you're encountering is that your spin operators transform like [pseudovectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) under reflection (similar to their classical angular momentum counterpart). One consequence is that the spin operators do not change signs under a parity transformation, so you won't be able to construct an operator like $S_{x}\rightarrow -S_{x}, S_{y}\rightarrow -S_{y}, S_{z}\rightarrow -S_{z}$.